# Laravel increment a variable inside HTML element

Tags: laravel

I am trying to implement searching feature in laravel. Everything is working fine. I am passing the html table data in a variable and parsing it later.

The problem is I could not figure out how to increment a value inside the HTML element.

I am trying this

```
foreach ($studentDetails as $indexkey=>$studentDetail){
                    $output .= "<tr><td>". $indexkey + 1 ."</td></tr>";
                }
```

This is not going to work as string concatenation is being done in the value. Any idea on how to increment the value by 1.

Comment: what do you want to get final result??

Comment: I want to pass the result to JQuery and display in blade template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this below: Take a variable for increment before the output variable and use that in output variable:-

```
 foreach ($studentDetails as $indexkey=>$studentDetail){
                $temp = $indexkey + 1;
                $output .= "<tr><td>". $temp ."</td></tr>";
            }
```

Comment: Yea I can do that. But looking something inline.

Comment: then you need to make that as an expression like so : $output .= "<tr><td>". ($indexkey + 1) ."</td></tr>";

Comment: Perfect. Didn't know about the expression